# Chrome developer tools: MEMORY Head snapshot: Getting text information from a head snapshot file

Tags: memory, binary-files, google-chrome-devtools

I have had a Google Form done with a long textual intro, that was accidentally erased by a colleague. The text is important to me, its about a page long. I have, about 6 hours later followed the tips and did the Chrome Developer Tools memory head snapshot and searched for the key words and there was a preview about 1st half of the page, but I couldn't get the 2nd half of the page. The key words from the 2nd half didn't come up. So I saved a file about 250mb large. I opened it up in text editor but it was binary.

Does this mean that the 2nd half is simply not there? Can I get it from the Developer Tools window or do I need to convert the .headsnapshot file somehow?

This show the beginning of the missing page, but not all of it, I am clueless on how to dig out the rest:

[image: Screenshot]